# Django: request.user.is_authenticated() returning true in Template, but false in View

Tags: django

I am writing a simple login/logout form using Django form, and other packages.
In my logout, view this is what I have, but it appears that request.user.is_authenticated() is always returning false, because it always goes to the else statement.

```
def logout_view(request):
    try:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            logout(request)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("registration:login")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("User was never signed in")
    except:
        return HttpResponse("User was never logged in")
```

However, in my template.py, request.user.is_authenticated works fine. It returns "I am logged in", so why is it that my view one returns false? Thanks For the help :D

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>
{{ user.username }}


<form action="{% url 'registration:logout'%}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <p>I'm logged in</p>
    {% else %}
      <p>I am anonymous</p>
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="Log out"/>
</form>
```

Also, here is my urls.py

```
from . import views

app_name = 'registration'


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test', views.login, name='test'),
    url(r'^login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    url(r'^signup/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.signup,name='signup'),
    url(r'^logout/',views.logout_view,name='logout'),
    url(r'^update/(?P<userNet_id>[0-9]+)?',views.updateProfile,name='update'),
    url(r'^home/(?P<userNet_id>[0-9]+)?',views.homePage,name='home'),
]
```

Comment: show the view that renders the given template. Did you try adding `request.user.is_authenticated()` to that particular view?

Comment: did you print the request.user in view , if you getting Anonymous User , please write custom backends

Comment: Which template language are you using, the Django template language or Jinja2?